# Hebrews 2:7 "made man a little lower than the Elohim. Who is he referring to when he says 'man' and when he says 'Elohim'?

Tags: elohim

"...made man a little lower than the Elohim." Who is he referring to when he says '*man'* and who is he referring to when he says *'Elohim'*?
Could this verse be speaking about two completely different races i.e. Neolithic peoples compared to Homo Sapiens? Is this from the perspective of the Sumerian Neolithic race who say that the Homo Sapian race are their 'gods' and who refer to them as *'Elohim'* whilst referring to themselves as *'man'*?
Should we see this verse from a different perspective which recognizes that primitive man saw himself as 'man' or *slaves* and saw Homo Sapiens as 'gods'?
I refer here to the original indigenous occupants of Mesopotamia (the cradle of civilization) who lived in this area for tens of thousands of years before the arrival of Homo Sapiens.

Answer (score 1):

The original text of Heb 2:7 is:

> ἠλάττωσας αὐτὸν βραχύ τι παρ’ ἀγγέλους, δόξῃ καὶ τιμῇ ἐστεφάνωσας
> αὐτόν = You made him a little lower than the angels; You crowned him
> with glory and honor (BLB)

Note that the following is absent:

- the word "elohim"
- "man" or "human"

However, this appears to quote Ps 8:5 whose text is:

> וַתְּחַסְּרֵ֣הוּ מְּ֭עַט **מֵאֱלֹהִ֑ים** וְכָבֹ֖וד וְהָדָ֣ר
> תְּעַטְּרֵֽהוּ׃ = Yet You have made him a little lower than **God**, And
> You crown him with glory and majesty! (NASB)

It in the Hebrew of the Psalm 8 that we have "elohim" = God, but no "man" or "human".

Therefore, the real question should be: Why does Hebrew 2:7 (and the LXX behind it) translate "elohim" as "angels"?

The answer involves the fact that Hebrew is not Greek!  That is, the Hebrew "elohim" has a broader meaning that just "God".  The word can also mean (see BDB meaning below)

- Jehovah God
- any pagan gods
- human rulers and judges
- angels
- other heavenly beings

Thus, each instance must be decided on a case-by-case basis.  Clearly, the LXX translators (which Heb 2:7 quotes) decided that elohim in Ps 8:5 meant "angels".

**"him"** in Heb 2:7

The "him" in Heb 2:7 is clear and obvious reference to (mortal) "man" or "mankind" in the previous verse that was created by God.

I am unaware of any unambiguous reference to neolithic races in the NT.  Heb 2:7 certainly does not refer to them.

**APPENDIX - BDB Entry for אֱלהִים = "elohim"**

> 1 plural in number.
>
> a. rulers, judges, either as divine representatives at sacred places
> or as reflecting divine majesty and power: האלהים Exodus 21:6 (Onk ᵑ6,
> but τὸ κριτήριον τοῦ Θεοῦ ᵐ5) Exodus 22:7; Exodus 22:8; אלהים Exodus
> 22:8; Exodus 22:27 (ᵑ7 Ra AE Ew RVm; but gods, ᵐ5 Josephus Philo AV;
> God, Di RV; all Covt. code of E) compare 1 Samuel 2:25 see Dr.; Judges
> 5:8 (Ew, but gods ᵐ5; God ᵑ6 BarHebr.; יהוה ᵑ9 Be) Psalm 82:1; Psalm
> 82:6 (De Ew Pe; but angels Bl Hup) Psalm 138:1 (ᵑ6 ᵑ7 Rab Ki De; but
> angels ᵐ5 Calv; God, Ew; gods, Hup Pe Che).
>
> b. divine ones, superhuman beings including God and angels Psalm 8:6
> (De Che Br; but angels ᵐ5 ᵑ6 ᵑ7 Ew; God, RV and most moderns) Genesis
> 1:27 (if with Philo ᵑ7 Jerome De Che we interpret נעשה as God's
> consultation with angels; compare Job 38:7).
>
> c. angels Psalm Job 97:7 (ᵐ5 ᵑ6 Calv; but gods, Hup De Pe Che);
> compare בני (ה)אלהים = (the) sons of God, or sons of gods = angels Job
> 1:6; Job 2:1; Job 38:7; Genesis 6:2,4 (J; so ᵐ5 Books of Enoch &
> Jubilees Philo Jude Jude 1:6 2Peter 2:4 JosAnt. i. 3. 1, most ancient
> fathers and modern critics; against usage are sons of princes, mighty
> men, Onk and Rab.; sons of God, the pious, Theod Chrys Jerome
> Augustine Luther Calv Hengst; ᵐ5L read οἱ υιὁὶ τοῦ Θεοῦ), compare בני
> אלים.
>
> d. gods האלהים Exodus 18:11; Exodus 22:19 (E) 1 Samuel 4:8; 2Chron
> 2:4; Psalm 86:8; אלהי האלהים the God of gods, supreme God Deuteronomy
> 10:17; Psalm 136:2; אלהים Exodus 32:1,23 (JE) Judges 9:13; אלהים אחרים
> other gods Exodus 20:3; Exodus 23:13; Joshua 24:2,16 (E) Deuteronomy
> 31:18,20 (JE) Deuteronomy 5:7 + (17 t. in D, not P) Judges 2:12,17,19;
> Judges 10:13; 1 Samuel 8:8; 1 Samuel 26:19; 1 Kings 9:6,9 (= 2
> Chronicles 7:19,22) 2 Chronicles 11:4,10; 2 Chronicles 14:9; 2 Kings
> 5:17; 2 Kings 17:35,37,38; 2 Kings 22:17 (= 2 Chron 34:25) 2
> Chronicles 28:25; Jeremiah 1:16 + (18 t. Jeremiah) Hosea 3:1; אלהי
> (ה)נכר foreign gods Genesis 35:2,4; Joshua 24:20,23 (E) Deuteronomy
> 31:16 (JE) Judges 10:16; 1 Samuel 7:3; 2Chronicles 33:15; Jeremiah
> 5:19; נחור ׳א Genesis 31:53 (E); מצרים ׳א Exodus 12:12 (P) Jeremiah
> 43:12,13; האמרי ׳א Joshua 24:15 (E) Judges 6:10; ארם ׳א etc. Judges
> 10:6; אלהים מעשה ידי Deuteronomy 4:28; הגוים ׳א gods of the nations 2
> Kings 18:33; 2 Kings 19:12; Deuteronomy 29:17; 2Chronicles 32:17,19;
> Isaiah 36:18; Isaiah 37:12; העמים ׳א Deuteronomy 6:14; Deuteronomy
> 13:8; Judges 2:12; Psalm 96:5; 1 Chronicles 5:25; 1 Chronicles 16:26;
> 2Chronicles 32:13,14; כסף ׳א Exodus 20:23 (E); זהב ׳א Exodus 20:23 (E)
> Exodus 32:31 (JE); מַסֵּכָה ׳א Exodus 34:17 (J) Leviticus 19:4 (H).
>
> 2 Plural intensive.
>
> a. god or goddess, always with suffix 1 Samuel 5:7 (Dagon), Judges
> 11:24 (Chemosh), 1 Kings 18:24 (Baal), Judges 9:27; Daniel 1:2 (twice
> in verse); or construct לעשתרת מואב ׳צדנים לכמוש א ׳א to Ashtoreth
> goddess of the Zidonians, Chemosh god of Moab, etc. 1 Kings 11:33;
> הארץ ׳א god of the land 2 Kings 17:26 (twice in verse); 2 Kings 17:27,
> and so the Syrians suppose that Yahweh is a mountain-god and not a god
> of valleys 1 Kings 20:28.
>
> b. godlike one Exodus 4:16 (J; Moses in relation to Aaron), Exodus 7:1
> (P; in relation to Pharaoh), 1 Samuel 28:13 (the shade of Samuel),
> Psalm 45:7 (the Messianic king, O God, ᵐ5 ᵑ6 Jerome, most scholars
> ancient and modern, but thy throne is God's = God's throne AE Ki Thea
> Ew Hup, compare 1 Chronicles 28:5). c. works of God, or things
> specially belonging to him (see אֵל 5) הר אלהים Psalm 68:16; Ezekiel
> 28:14,16; אש אלהים Job 1:16; גן (ה)אלהים Ezekiel 28:13; Ezekiel
> 31:8,9. d. God (see 3 & 4).
>
> 3 הָאֱלֹהִים the (TRUE) God, הוא האלהים ׳י Yahweh is (the) God
> Deuteronomy 4:35,39; Deuteronomy 7:9; 1 Kings 8:60; 1 Kings 18:39
> (twice in verse); 2Chronicles 33:13; הוא האלהים Isaiah 45:18; האלהים
> ׳י Joshua 22:34 (P ?) 1 Kings 18:21,24; 2Chronicles 32:16; אתה הוא
> האלהים 2 Samuel 7:28; 1 Kings 18:37; 2 Kings 19:15; 1 Chronicles
> 17:26; Isaiah 37:16; Nehemiah 9:7; האלהים as subject or object is used
> in E 33 t., Chronicles 38 t., Eccl 31 t., Jonah 5 t., elsewhere
> Genesis 5:22,24; Genesis 6:9,11 (sources of P) Genesis 17:18 (P)
> Joshua 22:34 (P ?) Genesis 44:16 (J) Deuteronomy 4:35,39; Deuteronomy
> 7:9; Judges 6:36,39; Judges 7:14; Judges 10:14; Judges 16:28; Judges
> 21:2; 1 Samuel 10:3,7; 1 Samuel 14:36; 2 Samuel 2:27; 2 Samuel 6:7; 2
> Samuel 7:28; 2 Samuel 12:16; 1 Kings 8:60; 1 Kings 18:21,24 (twice in
> verse); 1 Kings 18:37,39 (twice in verse); 1 Kings 19:15 (Ephr) Job
> 2:10; Jeremiah 11:12; Isaiah 37:16; Isaiah 45:18; Psalm 108:14; Daniel
> 1:9,17; הקדוש ׳הא ׳י 1 Samuel 6:20; הגדול ׳הא ׳י Nehemiah 8:6; אשר
> ׳בירושלם הא Ezra 1:3; אדני האלהים Daniel 9:3; in many phrases, as איש
> האלהים the man of God, acting under divine authority and influence: =
> (a) angel Judges 13:6,8, (b) prophet (the term coming into use in the
> Northern kingdom in the age of Elijah 1 Samuel 9:9-10, compare אִישׁ
> הָרוּחַ Hosea 9:7): of Moses Deuteronomy 33:1; Joshua 14:6 (E) 1
> Chronicles 23:14; 2Chronicles 30:16; Ezra 3:2; Psalm 90:1; of Samuel 1
> Samuel 9:6-10; of David2Chronicles 8:14; Nehemiah 12:24,36; Shemaiah 1
> Kings 12:22 (= 2 Chronicles 11:2); Elijah, Elisha, and others of their
> time 1 Kings 13:1-31; 1 Kings 17:18-24; 1 Kings 20:28; 2 Kings 1:9-13;
> 2 Kings 4:7-42; 2 Kings 5:8-20; 2 Kings 6:6-15; 2 Kings 7:2-9; 2 Kings
> 8:2-11; 2 Kings 13:19; 2 Kings 23:16-17 (Ephr) 2 Chronicles 25:7,9;
> unnamed prophet 1 Samuel 2:27; Hanan Jeremiah 35:4; a later title of
> prophet was עֶבֶד האלהים the servant of God, used of Moses 1
> Chronicles 6:34; 2Chronicles 24:9; Nehemiah 10:30; Daniel 9:11. בית
> האלהים the house of God, Judges 18:31, especially late, Chronicles (52
> t.) Ecclesiastes 4:17; Daniel 1:2; ׳בית י ׳הא 1 Chronicles 22:1; ארון
> (ברית) האלהים the ark (of the covenant) of God Judges 20:27; 1 Samuel
> 4:1-5:12; 1 Samuel 14; 2 Samuel 6:1-7:29; 15(23 t.); 1 Chronicles 13;
> 1 Chronicles 15; 1 Chronicles 16; 2Chronicles 1:4 (13 t.); מטה האלהים
> the rod of God Exodus 4:20; Exodus 17:9 (E); הר האלהים the mount of
> God (Horeb) Exodus 3:1; Exodus 4:27; Exodus 18:5; Exodus 24:13 (E) 1
> Kings 19:8 (Ephr); מלאך האלהים the (theophanic) angel of God Genesis
> 31:11; Exodus 14:19 (E) Judges 6:20; Judges 13:6,9; 2 Samuel 14:17,20;
> 2 Samuel 19:28; in other combinations Exodus 18:16; Numbers 23:27 (E)
> Judges 20:2; 1 Samuel 4:8; 1 Samuel 5:11; 1 Samuel 10:5; 2 Samuel
> 16:23; 1 Kings 12:22; 1 Chronicles 21:7 + (14 t.) Psalm 87:3;
> Ecclesiastes 9:1.
>
> 4 אֱלֹהִים = God אֱלֹהִים אֱמֶת ׳י = Yahweh is God in truth Jeremiah
> 10:10.
>
> a. אלהים (as subject object direct or indirect) is used by P (50 t. in
> story of creation and deluge, elsewhere 28 t.), by E (91 t.), J
> chiefly in poetic sources Genesis 3:1,3,5 (twice in verse); Genesis
> 9:27; Genesis 39:9; Deuteronomy 32:17,39, by D (11 t.) Judges (21 t.)
> Samuel (50 t.) Kings (29 t.) Chronicles (45 t.); in Psalm 42-86 (180
> t. often by editorial change for an original יהוה), elsewhere Psalm
> 3:3; Psalm 5:11; Psalm 7:11; Psalm 7:12; Psalm 9:18; Psalm 10:4; Psalm
> 10:13; Psalm 14:1; Psalm 14:2; Psalm 14:5; Psalm 25:22; Psalm 36:2;
> Psalm 36:8; Psalm 77:14; Psalm 100:3; Psalm 108:2; Psalm 108:6; Psalm
> 108:8; Psalm 108:12 (twice in verse); Psalm 149:9; Job 5:8; Job 20:29;
> Job 28:23; Job 32:2; Job 34:9 (& in Prologue 6 t.) Proverbs 2:5;
> Proverbs 3:4; Proverbs 25:2; Ecclesiastes (7 t.) Hosea (5 t.); Amos
> 4:11 (כמהפכת אלתים את סדם as God overthrew Sodom = Jeremiah 50:40 =
> Isaiah 13:19) Zechariah 8:23; Zechariah 12:8; Micah 3:7 (but אליהם ᵐ5
> ᵑ6) Isaiah 35:4; Isa2 (9 t.); Jeremiah 10:10; Ezekiel (13 t.); Malachi
> (5 t.); Jonah (4 t.); the phrase לאלהים ׳היה ל Genesis 28:21 (ER)
> Genesis 17:7,8; Exodus 6:7; Exodus 29:45; Leviticus 11:45; Leviticus
> 22:33; Leviticus 25:38; Leviticus 26:12,45; Numbers 15:41 (P);
> Deuteronomy 26:17; Deuteronomy 29:13; 2 Samuel 7:24 (= 1 Chronicles
> 17:22); Zechariah 8:8; Jeremiah (6 t.); Ezekiel (6 t.); אלהים צדיק
> righteous God Psalm 7:10; קדשים ׳א holy God Joshua 24:19 (E); חיים ׳א
> living God Deuteronomy 5:23; 1 Samuel 17:26,36; Jeremiah 10:10;
> Jeremiah 23:36; חי ׳א 2 Kings 19:4,16 (= Isaiah 37:4,17). For the
> phrases ׳יהוה א, צבאות ׳א ׳י, צבאות ׳א, ׳י ׳אל א, ׳יה א, ׳צבאות א ׳י,
> אלתי ׳י, צבאות, ׳אדני א see יהוה, יה, צבאות & אדני.
>
> b. construct אֱלֹהֵי (a) with persons אֱלֹהֵי אַבְרָהָם = God of
> Abraham, a phrase of J, Genesis 26:24; Genesis 28:13; Genesis 31:53,
> elsewhere Psalm 47:10; 1 Kings 18:36; 1 Chronicles 29:18; 2Chronicles
> 30:6; אדני אברהם ׳א Genesis 24:12,27,42,48 (J); אלהי אב father's God
> (various suffix & names), a phrase of E, Genesis 31:5,29,42; Genesis
> 46:3; Genesis 50:17; Exodus 3:6,13,15,16; Exodus 15:2; Exodus 18:4;
> Joshua 18:3, elsewhere Genesis 32:10; Genesis 43:23 (J) Exodus 4:5 (J
> ?) Deuteronomy (8 t.); Judges 2:12; 2 Kings 21:22; Chronicles (31 t.);
> Daniel 11:37; אֱלֹהֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל Israel's God, phrase of E, Genesis
> 33:20; Exodus 5:1; Exodus 24:10; Exodus 32:27; Joshua 8:30; Joshua
> 14:14; Joshua 22:16; Joshua 24:2,23, elsewhere Exodus 34:23; Joshua
> 7:13,19,20 (JE) Numbers 16:9; Joshua 9:18,19; Joshua 22:24; Joshua
> 10:40,42; Joshua 13:14,33 (R see Di Joshua 7:13) Judges 4:6; Judges
> 5:3,5; Judges 6:8; Judges 11:21,23; Judges 21:3; 1 Samuel 1:17 + (20
> t.) Kings (26 t.) Chronicles (45 t.); Psalm 41:14; Psalm 106:48
> (doxology) Psalm 59:6; Psalm 69:7; Isaiah 17:6; Isaiah 21:10,17;
> Isaiah 29:23; Isa3, Isaiah 24:15; Isaiah 37:16,21; Isa2, Isaiah 41:17
>
> - (6 t.); Jeremiah 35:17 + (48 t.); Ezekiel 8:4 + (7 t.); Zephaniah 2:9; Malachi 2:16; Ruth 2:12; מערכות ישראל ׳א God of the battle array
>   of Israel 1 Samuel 17:45; ׳א יַעֲקֹב 2 Samuel 23:1 (poetry) Psalm
>   20:2; Psalm 46:8; Psalm 46:12; Psalm 75:10; Psalm 76:7; Psalm 81:2;
>   Psalm 81:5; Psalm 84:9; Psalm 94:7; Isaiah 2:3 (= Micah 4:2); העבריים
>   ׳א God of the Hebrews Exodus 3:18; Exodus 5:3; Exodus 7:16; Exodus
>   9:1,13 (JE); it is used with other proper names, Nahor Genesis 31:53
>   (E), Shem Genesis 9:26 (J), David 2 Kings 20:5; 2Chronicles 21:12;
>   34:3; Isaiah 38:5, Hezekiah 2Chronicles 32:17, Elijah 2 Kings 2:14;
>   ארני המלך ׳א the God of my lord the king 1 Kings 1:36. (β) with nouns
>   of attributes or relationships, קֶרֶם ׳א ancient God Deuteronomy
>   33:27; עולם ׳א everlasting God Isaiah 40:28; אֱמֶת ׳א true
>   God2Chronicles 15:3; אָמֵן ׳א Isaiah 65:16 (see אָמֵן); משפט ׳א Isaiah
>   30:18; Malachi 2:17; מרום ׳א Micah 6:6; כָל בָשָׂר ׳א God of all flesh
>   Jeremiah 32:27; compare ׳א הרוחות לכל בשר Numbers 16:22; Numbers 27:16
>   (P); השמים ׳א God of heaven Genesis 24:7 (JR) 2 Chronicles 36:23; Ezra
>   1:2; Nehemiah 1:4,5; Nehemiah 2:4,20; compare כל הארץ ׳א Isaiah 54:5;
>   ׳השמים וא ׳א ׳י הארץ Genesis 24:3 (JR); מִקָּרֹב ׳א a God at hand
>   opposed to מֵרָחֹק ׳א Jeremiah 23:23, ישועתי ׳א, יִשְׁעִי ׳א God of my
>   salvation Psalm 18:47 (= 2 Samuel 22:47) Psalm 24:5; Psalm 25:5; Psalm
>   27:9; Psalm 65:6; Psalm 79:9; Psalm 85:5; Isaiah 17:10; Micah 7:7;
>   Habakkuk 3:18; 1 Chronicles 16:35; ישועתי ׳א Psalm 88:2; תשועתי ׳א
>   Psalm 51:16; צִדְקִי ׳א God of righteousness Psalm 4:2; חַסְדִּי ׳א
>   Psalm 59:11; Psalm 59:18; צוּרִי ׳א God who is my rock 2 Samuel 22:3
>   (compare Psalm 18:3); מָעוּזִּי֯ ׳א God who is my stronghold Psalm
>   43:2; תְהִלָּתִי ׳א God who is my praise Psalm 109:1.
>
> c. with suffix in P (22 t. including phrase ויראת מאלהיך) Leviticus
> 19:14,32; Leviticus 25:17,36,43 (H) Exodus 8:21; Joshua 24:27 (E)
> Deuteronomy 32:37 (poetry) Joshua 9:23 (JE) Deuteronomy 10:21;
> Deuteronomy 31:17; Judges 10:10; Judges 16:23,24; 1 Samuel 10:19; 2
> Samuel 10:12; 2 Samuel 22:32 + (4 t. poetry) 1 Kings 12:28; 1 Kings
> 20:23; 2 Kings 19:10; Chronicles (83 t.); Psalms (62 t.); Proverbs
> 2:17; Proverbs 30:9; Ruth 1:15,16 (twice in verse); Isaiah 1:10;
> Isaiah 7:13; Isaiah 8:19,21; Isa2 (29 t.); Jeremiah 5:4,5; Jeremiah
> 23:36; Jeremiah 51:5; Ezekiel 34:31; Daniel (5 t.); Hosea (12 t.);
> Amos 2:8; Amos 4:12; Joel 1:13 (twice in verse); Joel 1:16; Joel 2:17;
> Micah 6:8; Micah 7:7; Jonah 1:5,6; Zephaniah 3:2; Nahum 1:14;
> Zechariah 9:7; Zechariah 12:5; אלהים with suffix is also used with
> יהוה several hundred times (see יהוה).

Answer (score 1):

**A Couple Clarifications**

First, Hebrews 2:7 does not contain the word "elohim."  That is a Hebrew word, but the book of Hebrews was written in Greek.

Secondly, Hebrews 2:7 quotes from Psalm 8:5. But Psalm 8:5 does not have the word "man" in it: it has only the pronoun for "him."

**"Man"**

The word "man" comes from Psalm 8:4, the verse just prior to the one quoted.  In it, the Hebrew word "אֱנֹ֥ושׁ" (Strong's H582: ĕ·nō·wōš) is the source of the translation "man."  This is different from the typical "אָדָ֗ם/Adam" (Strong's H120) which is used for "man" in the subsequent phrase "son of man."

The "man" (enowsh: H582) first used in Psalm 8:4 is often used of servants and of strangers, and can mean "mortal" or more generally "mankind."  The second expression, "son of man" (literally "son of Adam"), may have prophetic implications, in addition to referencing the children of Adam generally.

Some of my Hebrew teachers would tend toward a more strict interpretation, applying "son of man" literally to a male, and not merely to a "child" of either gender.  While the Hebrew is certainly masculine, some will be inclined to apply it to persons more generally, assuming that it does not apply to a specific "son" nor to only a male.

**"Elohim"**

The Hebrew word for "elohim" (H430: אֱלֹהִ֑ים) is most commonly translated as "God" or "gods", depending on the grammatical context.  In Psalm 8:5, however, it is translated as "angels."  The word has broad application in Hebrew and is not limited to deity.  It is sometimes even used for human judges, as it is in Exodus 22:8.

> If the thief be not found, then the master of the house shall be
> brought unto **the judges** (הָֽאֱלֹהִ֑ים/hā·’ĕ·lō·hîm), to see whether he have put his hand unto his
> neighbor's goods. (Exodus 22:8, KJV)

In Hebrews 2:7 where Psalm 8:5 is quoted in Greek, the word "elohim" is quoted as "ἀγγέλους/anggelous" (angels).  This tells us that the Biblical author of Hebrews understood "elohim" to contextually reference angels in this Psalm.

### Conclusion

In answer to the question: *"Who is he referring to when he says 'man' and who is he referring to when he says 'Elohim'?"*, it is reasonable to conclude that "man" refers to mankind generally, and "angels" (from Hebrew "elohim") represents heavenly beings.